# Configuring VSCode for SSH Development via a Jump Server on Linux

Tags: ssh, vscode-remote

I'm currently working on a development setup where I need to use VSCode on Windows to develop on a Linux server via SSH.

When I connect to a jump server using XShell, I log in with a username and password. Upon successful login, I'm presented with a menu to select the target server:

```
Selected Group: some description
1. Server A
2. Server B
3. Server C 
Select server:
```

After selecting the appropriate server by typing 1, 2, or 3 and then enter, I'm directly logged into it without needing to enter credentials.

But I want to use VSCode this time. I've attempted to configure VSCode's SSH settings as follows:

```
Host TheJumpServer
  HostName 10.10.10.10
  Port 22
  User myusername
```

When I try to connect to the jump server through VSCode, it prompts me for my password. After entering it, VSCode seems to hang for an extended period before ultimately displaying an error message:

```
Got bad result from install script.
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to configure VSCode to recognize the server selection process and successfully connect to the desired target server through the jump server. Any suggestions or insights into the correct configuration would be greatly appreciated.